# OpenGL Display Lists slower than immediate mode?

Tags: c++, opengl

Okay, before anyone tries to kill me, I know that I should leave this god-forsaken technique for drawing in OpenGL. But I'm writing a simple 2D game and I don't really know much about VBOs and shaders. So I was using immediate mode to populate the screen with polygons, but I read that Display Lists should be much faster than immediate mode. So I went and tried it, but I'm getting half of the FPS that I was getting using immediate mode. I'm not initializing the list in every frame, I'm using the for loop below to draw a grid:

```
glPushMatrix();
for(int y = 0; y < 56; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 80; x++)
    {
        glCallList(grid);
        glTranslatef(GRID_WIDTH, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    glTranslatef(-80*GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT, 0.0f); 

}
glPopMatrix();
```

I don't think the for loop is to blame because I tried the same code except I changed glCallList to immediate mode codes and the FPS was higher still. Why is this happening?

Comment: In this case, you probably want to render your entire grid into a display list.  Although this requires re-builiding the list if `GRID_WIDTH` is changed, this can still be done at run-time with little performance hit (assuming the value is changed infrequently, like when the user changes the UI size or resizes the window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entire block should be in a display list, not the innermost bit.

The idea is to give OpenGL a *big* block of stuff to optimize.

Wrapping what appears to be a single quad in a display list doesn't really buy you anything other than a small reduction in function-call overhead.

Comment: I see, but what if I'm rendering stuff according to a map file? Or update individual grids? I don't think writing all the code in a display list can help me with "dynamic" rendering, so to speak

Comment: Yep, you're right.  If everything is dynamic you're SOL.

Comment: What is your recommendation in this case, should I be learning about VBOs?

Comment: Yep, though they don't really help you with the dynamic problem.  They *do* let you blast everything into server memory in big chunks though.  Once it's in server memory you can render all/parts of a VBO relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer (since I can't comment yet), it's worth noting that modern drivers will try to optimize immediate mode rendering by batching them up and converting them to DrawArrays or similar commands behind the scenes. So although you should use the modern/faster stuff and it *should* perform better, sometimes you will see situations where it appears to be slower. One possible cause in that case is that your implementation of using newer techniques is less efficient than what the driver was converting your old draws to.